# Create preloader with % for gallery page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I'd like to build a preloader for a very big gallery page, with jQuery.
The idea is that, after checked the total number of images, I'll animate the progress bar step by step once a single image is loaded. This is what I did:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loadingBar = $('#preload-overlay').find('span.meter');
    var totalImg = $('img').length;
    var totalLength = parseInt($('#preload-overlay').find('div.progress').css("width"), 10);
    var step = (totalLength / totalImg).toFixed(4);

    $('img').on('load', function() {
        loadingBar.animate({
            width: '+=' + step + 'px' 
        }, 1);
    });
});
```

The result is random! Sometimes, the progress bar fills up a little more than `100%`, and sometimes (when I reload the page without cleaning cache), the progress bar stops filling too early. This is my first attempt, is the base idea good but the realization is wrong? Or I'm facing the problem from the wrong side?
Thank you for help.

EDIT
I added gallery id to jquery selectors, and apparently solved the issue.

```
$('#galleria img')....
```

The only issue now is in firefox: if I reload the page, all is fine, but when I reach the page from another one, it fill the bar for only 15/20%